# TSQL - Case on Ntext (SQL 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Stored Procedures in SQL 2005 - with field type NText

Im Writing a stored procedure to tidy up some data before importing it into Microsoft CRM. 
So far all works fine.

However i need to do a case statement on a nText Field. It needs to check this field against about 3 or 4 text values and set a new field (already in the destination table) which is also an nText field.

However i am getting the error
"The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I have come across a few articles however their solutions all seem very complex.

Thanks for your help and advice in advanced.

Comment: May I ask you what kind of checks do you have to perform on these NText fields?

I'm not sure a CASE again a NText field would be efficient, as it could contain a significant amount of data. Maybe there's a more efficient approach, depending on what you would like to do.

Comment: I know where the confusion is coming in now. 

First i created an entity in MS CRM. I then used a program to create a copy of the table in SQL (this allows me to sync later). However all text fields were created as nText. 

The data its self is 3-5 chrs long and the new text is 2-5 chrs long.

Comment: Wow, talking about overkill... Then you should have no problem if you convert the nText fields to a reasonable sized varchar.

Comment: changing both the fields on each table fixed the issue, and it also imported correctly into CRM

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend, if at all possible, replacing the NTEXT type with NVARCHAR(MAX), since NTEXT is not a first class type and NVARCHAR is. This should be easy to do with an ALTER TABLE statement.

Most higher level code shouldn't care about the type change. Any procedural code that uses READTEXT, WRITETEXT, etc. to deal with the NTEXT columns can be simplified to just basic selects and updates.

If the type change is not possible you may have to wrap the comparisons and assignments with CAST() or CONVERT() operators, which is ugly.

Comment: I changed the two database fields, from ntext to varchar. this solved my SP problem. After this luckily the sync. back into CRM worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

NTEXT is deprecated in SQL Server 2005. You should use NVARCHAR(MAX) instead (NVARCHAR(MAX) can be used in CASE). Is it possible for you to change the type?

Comment: Yea i took a look at that. I will need to try it out, we have a product that syncs. SQL tables with CRM so long as that can cope it should be fine, if not i will need to find a solution.

Comment: check my sample below. that works fine as well. it uses a NTEXT that is casted to NVARCHAR(MAX) and used in a CASE. good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

this works as well

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    MyDummy NTEXT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (MyDummy) Values ('test')

SELECT 
CASE CAST(MyDummy AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) WHEN 'test' THEN 'ok' ELSE 'NOK' END MyTest
FROM #temp

drop table #temp
```